# Shopify Order Creation Guzzle 6

Tags: php, heroku, http-post, guzzle6, shopify-app

I've created a private shopify app to create orders via shopify api. Following code is used.

```
   $client = new Client(); 
            $result = $client->post($url, [
                'order' => [
                    'email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
                'fulfillment_status' => 'unfulfilled',
                    'line_items' =>  
                                 array("variant_id" => 42837938757,
                                        "quantity" => 5)
                        ]
                    ]);
```

But this returns Http 500.
Heroku Log
[image: Heroku Log]

I've tried the code in different ways, for example archived an order using post method, and it worked. I'm using Guzzle 6 version, probably this might be a problem with json parsing. Can anybody help with a workaround with this issue?

Comment: What's the API end-point you are requesting?

Comment: admin/orders.json